# Installing OpenCV into PyCharm

Tags: opencv, intellij-idea, computer-vision, pycharm, pytorch

Idk if this is a stackoverflow-appropriate post so forgive if the question is misplaced.  I'm trying to install OpenCV into my Pycharm IDE through the conda virtual environment.  I typed `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` inside the PyCharm terminal and it has been doing this for 11 hours and God knows how many more to go.

[image]

Pycharm did this with PyTorch as well.  Am I doing something wrong or is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can install packages directly in PyCharm by going to `file->settings` select `Project Interpreter` and click on the '+' icon on the top right (see image)
[image]
I would recommend creating a `requirements.txt` file in the root of your project, and write down all your required packages. When a package is missing, PyCharm will automatically suggest to install the package for you.

e.g. for installing opencv you can add the following to you `requirements.txt`

```
opencv-python
```

Or even specify the version that your project needs

```
opencv-python==4.1.2
```

edit: the advantage of using a `requirement.txt` is that you can more easily port the project to another machine, and re-install the packages if needed.

Comment: How do you create the `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @OnurOzbek you can create the file in the root of your project, e.g. by navigating to the directory in your file explorer and create a new file named `requirements.txt`, or directly in PyCharm by selecting your project in the project panel on the left, and then choose`file`->`New...` select `File` and fill in the name `requirements.txt`

Comment: What I meant to ask was, what does the file entail?  How do I create its content?

Comment: @OnurOzbek The contents represents the pip-packages that your project depends on (e.g. opencv-python in your case). You can write a dependency on each line. It's a text file, you can edit it in any text-edit you like, including PyCharm.

Comment: I should've been more clear.  How do I write it?  Do I follow a certain syntax or just list the names of the packages?

Comment: You can just write the names of the packages. For more info on the format of `requirements.txt` see https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html